# Bootstrap alignment and spacing of vertical checkboxes with associated horizontal text fields

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, radio-button

What is the most elegant (ie. non-hacky) way to properly align a group of checkboxes, one or more of which have associated text inputs? Whatever I have tried, I end up with (i) unevenly spaced checkboxes, or (ii) misaligned checkboxes, or (iii) misaligned labels, or (iv) misaligned text boxes.

Since the use case of:

What is your favourite food?
(a) Apple
(b) Banana
(c) Carrot
(d) Other: _______

is surely very common, I wonder whether anyone has found a way to do this with Bootstrap standard classes, before I start forcing my own classes into the code.

Here is the code I have now:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                       Favourite food
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <fieldset class="form-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                                    Apple
                                 </fieldset>   
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <fieldset class="form-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                                    Banana 
                                </fieldset>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <fieldset class="form-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox"/>
                                        Other <input type="email" placeholder="someone@somewhere.com" class="form-control"/>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <fieldset class="form-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox"/> Any fruit from one of these colour groups: <a href="">Red, Green, Blue</a>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Screenshot attached showing output in Chrome:
[image: Screenshot showing uneven spacing and alignment]

The fourth checkbox is too far from the third, while the text and 'input type=text' on the third line are too low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple bootstrap way, just change the code of the checkbox to this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <label>                                    
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            Other 
        </label>   
        <input type="email" placeholder="someone@somewhere.com" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/qMoAyk4jQf)

Comment: Hi Sebsemillia - that's pretty nifty and helps line things up! I just had the tags in the wrong places. Your answer doesn't help with spacing the checkboxes evenly, though. In your code snippet, the third row still has more padding than the others, making the vertical spacing of the checkboxes uneven. Any ideas?

Comment: Well the extra spacing comes because of the default size of the text `input`. Since `.input-sm` on the text input is still too big for your needs, I'm afraid there is no other way then adjusting the padding of the other checkboxes manually.

Comment: It's getting crazy beyond that to add further inline radio buttons after the "other" text box. Bootstrap handles it very poorly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to achieve what you're trying to do. The only change which I've made to your HTML structure is that I've wrapped the description for each checkbox inside a `<span>` tag and added used this CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: relative !important;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's a working demo:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative !important;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-inline .form-control {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Favourite food</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <fieldset class="form-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Apple</span>

        </fieldset>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <fieldset class="form-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Banana</span> 
        </fieldset>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <fieldset class="form-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Other</span> 
          <input type="email" placeholder="someone@somewhere.com" class="form-control" />
        </fieldset>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <fieldset class="form-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Any fruit from one of these colour groups: <a href="">Red, Green, Blue</a></span>

        </fieldset>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Fahad. Many thanks for that. The output is the same as Sebsemillia's answer above but I'm afraid (a) is less elegant because you've created your own classes, and (b) suffers from the same problem regarding uneven spacing of checkboxes.

Comment: @MSC It's completely fine to add a `<span>` tag and doesn't make the code any less `elegant`. Secondly, the uneven spacing of the checkboxes is because of the height of the input field next to `Others`. I've updated my answer above and if you run the code snippet in full page, you can see that the checkboxes are now evenly spaced now that I've reduced the height of the input field.

Comment: Thanks, Fahad. I appreciate the time you put in. I prefer all my text boxes to be the standard height, though.